# Why does dotnet build on a .NET Framework 4.5 project throw "This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, winappdriver

The sample [NotepadAndCalculatorTest](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/C%23/NotepadAndCalculatorTest) project built in VS Code using the terminal command `dotnet build` throws the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(820,5): error : The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'NotepadCalculatorTest.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, 
and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\<username>\VSCode Projects\WinAppDriverTryout\Test\Samples\C#\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\NotepadCalculatorTest.csproj]
```

Or:

```
NotepadCalculatorTest.csproj(109,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props.
```

Could someone point me towards a possible way to get rid of the errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) carries out an [implicit restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#implicit-restore) as part of the command.**

**This uses [`dotnet restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) which does not support project references in `packages.config` & is exactly what this project is using.**

`dotnet restore` only supports `.csproj` package references.

That's why, this project builds perfectly fine in Visual Studio but `dotnet build` throws errors.

You *can* migrate `packages.config` to package references by right-clicking on the file within Visual Stduio and clicking migrate, however that still won't fix your problem as `dotnet cli` works properly with .NET Framework only if the project was created using the `dotnet new` command.

I assume this project was created in Visual Studio since it has a Visual Studio solution file - `.sln` - and so commonly have a differently structured `.csproj` format.

This then usually breaks some CLI commands, even if you migrate the references in this case.

You have 2 workarounds.

---

**1. Use [`nuget restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore)**

The easiest option is to download the NuGet CLI executable from [here](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe), taken from the [downloads page](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

If you are not on Windows, use [this guide by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#nugetexe-cli).

Add it to your PATH or place it in the root folder of the project.

Run `nuget restore`, which is compatible with `packages.config` (run `.\nuget restore` if you're inside PowerShell to trust the command as PowerShell does not does not load commands from the current location by default for security).

Your should get output similar to this:

```
PS C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest> .\nuget restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.9.0.16703' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.WinAppDriver.Appium.WebDriver.1.0.1-Preview.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.Support.3.8.0.
Restoring NuGet package Selenium.WebDriver.3.8.0.
Restoring NuGet package Castle.Core.4.2.1.
Restoring NuGet package MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3.
Restoring NuGet package MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0.
Adding package 'MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Adding package 'Selenium.Support.3.8.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Adding package 'Castle.Core.4.2.1' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Adding package 'Microsoft.WinAppDriver.Appium.WebDriver.1.0.1-Preview' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Adding package 'Selenium.WebDriver.3.8.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Adding package 'MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.WinAppDriver.Appium.WebDriver.1.0.1-Preview' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'Selenium.Support.3.8.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'Selenium.WebDriver.3.8.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'Castle.Core.4.2.1' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'
Added package 'MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0' to folder 'C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\packages'

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\StackOverflow\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.FallbackLocation.config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    C:\Users\StackOverflow\.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

Installed:
    7 package(s) to packages.config projects
```

Then run `dotnet build`.

It won't try to run `dotnet restore` as the packages have already been restored by NuGet already so you won't get any errors:

```
PS C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest> dotnet build 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
  NotepadCalculatorTest -> C:\Users\StackOverflow\NotepadAndCalculatorTest\bin\Debug\NotepadCalculatorTest.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.08
```

---

**2. Port the project**

The 2nd workaround is to create a new project using [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) & port the code over so that your `.csproj` file works with `dotnet restore` and subsequently, `dotnet build`.

---

I would recommend option 1 unless you don't want to restore via NuGet.

Comment: Thank you, @Ermiya for your answer, which worked!

I cloned a fresh set of files from the project in Github and then followed your instructions.

I did a `nuget restore` followed by a `dotnet build` in a CMD command window. Both ran successfully without errors. I repeat the same in VS Code's terminal and the result is similarly successful without errors.

Next I will compare the content of the csproj file and the other file types to see what the differences were that caused the previous restores and builds to fail.

Comment: @Seibernaut You're welcome for the answer and to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Found that the version that currently is working do not have any files modified except for those new files and package folders resulted from the `nuget restore` and the `dotnet build`.   

The package folders created by `nuget restore' are:   
.\packages\Castle.Core.4.2.1   
.\packages\Microsoft.WinAppDriver.Appium.WebDriver.1.0.1-Preview   
.\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0    
.\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0    
.\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3   
.\packages\Selenium.Support.3.8.0
.\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.3.8.0

Comment: Yes correct - it's the package restore which fails using dotnet build as it does not support packages.config